# Install all perl dependence modules through cpan

Tags: perl

I have developed the one perl application is working fine with one server. I copied the same application to the other server when i run the that application it's keep on asking perl dependence module, later i got to know through CPAN we can resolve those dependencies but when i try to work with CPAN it unable to download dependence perl module. I have set the `http_porxy` and `connect_to_internet_ok` to `yes` but still unable to install perl module.

Run through CPAN command prompt getting below error:

```
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to cpan.strawberryperl.com:80 (10060)]
Warning: no success downloading 'C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.txt
.gz.tmp13940'. Giving up on it.
```

Please help us to resolve the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Proxy is the issue here. Setting proxy for cpan :

```
cpan> o conf init /proxy/
Your ftp_proxy? [] ftp://1.1.1.1:3128
Your http_proxy? [] http://1.1.1.1:3128
Your no_proxy? []
cpan> o conf commit
```

This method of setting proxy has always worked for me. I used these steps on Linux but I guess it should not be different on windows as well.